# Laravel 9 - Can you use nested Folders with Lang Directories?

Tags: localization, laravel-9

To make my project support localisation for both frontend views and with Controllers for notifications/warnings etc I was considering nesting the lang files in a mirrored structure as the views themselves?

For example my view of:

```
app/resources/views/user/profile.blade.php
```

Would have a lang file of:

```
app/resources/lang/en/user/profile.php
```

Now lets say my lang file simply contains a title:

```
<?php
return [
    'title'=>"Welcome to Your Profile",
]
?>
```

And my profile.blade.php simply contains this. I have attempted to access the profile.title as follows but it just displays:

```
<h2 class="page-title mb-0">{{__('user.profile.title')}}</h2>
<h2 class="page-title mb-0">'user.profile.title</h2>
```

Is this possible, I've attempted to Google this approach but all the examples I could find don't mention this but I would assume larger apps systems would need this to make localisation manageable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my continued research into this it appears you cannot have a set of nested folders of configs and be able to access it as I queried above.

The format works the exact same way as the config so you could have a file user.php and have an array of profile containing a key of title and access it like this:

```
{{__('user.profile.title)}}
```

It just means if you have a complex system you will end up with a lot of files or few large ones.

Comment: It doesn't work to me..this solution render to me mypath.myfilename.mystring in html...